# Possible to do a HTTP request to API to get Presence Data from a Lync 2010 server

Tags: php, lync, lync-2010, user-presence, ucwa

Just wanted to check whether its possible to do an HTTP request to get Presence data on Lync 2010, sort of like how it done on Lync 2007 e.h.

```
   <cwaRequests xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/rtc/cwa" sid="91">
    <queryPresence rid="4">
      <uris>
          <uri>sip:jessicaa@contoso.com</uri>
      </uris>
    </queryPresence>
   </cwaRequests>
```

I wanted to make this request from a PHP script on a Linux machine. Is this possible, without having to install any additional software?

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You could write a UCMA application and expose the functionality to query presence data for a specific SIP.  There are not really any exposed Web APIs in Lync Server 2010.

Comment: That was what I was worried, was hoping there was some kind of Web API. Well we were proposing to writing an application to to get presence data. Would you happen to recommend any good sites or tutorials on how to approach this? Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in creating a Web Service that exposes UCMA functionality you will want to consider looking into:

- Download the [UCMA 4.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35463)
- If you have access to PluralSight it would be worth checking out [Introduction to UCMA 4.0](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/ucma4-introduction) and if not you may need to spend some time on MSDN looking over https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466088.aspx
- Samples that are part of the UCMA SDK - [SubscribePresence (QuickStart)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454835.aspx) / [SubscribePresenceView (QuickStart)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454838.aspx)

Some things to keep in mind when designing/devloping the Web API portion is that UCMA is a 64-bit assembly meaning you should not expect to run it under a 32-bit process.  IF you ever forget this you will run into an issue with a dependent assembly called [SIPEPS not being found](http://blog.greenl.ee/2012/08/21/error-sipeps-dll-ucma-4-0/).

Once you have your feet wet with UCMA you will want to look into developing a Web API to expose this UMCA presence functionality.  I will leave the Web API portion a little sparse as there are many different options on how to host and expose a Web API, but I would suggest looking into [Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

The two current web-based API's [Skype Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/skypewebsdk) and [UCWA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0) aren't supported on Lync 2010. I think the only way is as @ShellbyZ has said, exposing a UCMA 4 application through a Web API.